# EntityManager different instances inconsistence using getRepository() factory method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hi i have this structure: Home N <-> N Groups

**Home.orm.yml**

```
manyToMany:
    groups:
      targetEntity: Domain\Entity\Group
      inversedBy: homes
      joinTable:
        name: homes_groups
        joinColumns:
          home_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: CASCADE
        inverseJoinColumns:
          group_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: CASCADE
```

**Home.php**

```
protected $groups;
protected $name;
public function __construct($name, Group $group) {
 $this->name = $name;
 $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
 $this->addGroup($group);
}
public function getGroups() {
 return $this->groups();
}
public function addGroup(Group $group) {
    if (!$this->getGroups()->contains($group)) {
        $this->getGroups()->add($group);
        $group->addUser($this);
    }
}
```

**Group.orm.yml**

```
manyToMany:
    homes:
      targetEntity: Domain\Entity\Home
      orderBy: { 'name': 'ASC' }
      mappedBy: groups
```

**Group.php**

```
protected $homes;
public function __construct() {
 $this->homes = new ArrayCollection();
}
public function getHomes() {
 return $this->homes();
}
public function addHome(Home $home) {
    if (!$this->getHomes()->contains($home)) {
        $this->getHomes()->add($home);
    }
}
```

Repositories are injected as a service with this yaml:

```
  repository.group:
    class: Infrastructure\Persistence\DoctrineORM\Repository\GroupRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
      - 'Domain\Entity\Group'
  repository.home:
    class: Infrastructure\Persistence\DoctrineORM\Repository\HomeRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
      - 'Domain\Entity\Home'
```

This always worked untile last week, now when i run this code it rise an exception:

```
$group = $groupRepo->find(3); // Group#code = 'A'
$home = new Home('test', $group);
$homeRepo->getEntityManger->persist($home);
$homeRepo->getEntityManger->flush();
```

It stop with this exception:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Domain\Entity\Home#groups' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Domain\Entity\Group@0000000012724e2a00000000138c9399. To solve t
>     his issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot fi
>     nd out which entity causes the problem implement 'Domain\Entity\Group#__toString()' to get a clue.

Obviously if i put the `cascade: ["persist"]` into the yaml configuration of Home#groups i get another exception:

> SQL exception Duplicate entry [....] INSERT INTO groups (code) VALUES (?): ['A']

The only way to make it work again is to use GroupRepository to persist the Home Entity:

```
$group = $groupRepo->find(3);
$home = new Home('test', $group);
$groupRepo->getEntityManger->persist($home);
$groupRepo->getEntityManger->flush();
```

And everything works, Home created and present into the Home table, a new row gets created into the join table

It seems that even if use "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" for instantiate every repository (using a factory method) i have different EntityManager instances for each Repository.

```
$g = $groupRepo->find(1);
$groupRepo->getEntityManager()->contains($g); // true
$user = new User()...
$user->addGroup($g);
$userRepo->getEntityManager()->contains($user); // false
$userRepo->getEntityManager()->contains($user->getGroups()->first()); // false

spl_object_hash($groupRepo->getEntityManger()) // e.g. abc123
spl_object_hash($userRepo->getEntityManager()) // e.g. 456cdef
```

**USING FIXTURE's ObjectManager WORKS**

If i put the above code inside a Fixture and i use directly the ObjectManager, everything works well:

```
class HomesFixtureLoader implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface {
// ...
 public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
 {
   $group = $this->container->get('groupRepo')->find(3);
   $home = new Home('test', $group)
   $manager->persist($home);
   $manager->flush();
 }
}
```

In the fixture i try to print the spl object hash

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $groupRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $homeRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');

    die(print_r([spl_object_hash($groupRepo->getEntityManager()),
        spl_object_hash($homeRepo->getEntityManager()),
        spl_object_hash($manager)], true));
}

// RESULT
Array
(
    [0] => 00000000024ed69f00000000656e0ce9
    [1] => 00000000024ed12000000000656e0ce9
    [2] => 00000000024ed69f00000000656e0ce9
)
```

As you can see the GroupRepository EntityManager is the same as the ObjectManager of the Fixture while the HomeRepository's EntityManager is different. This is why i think saving the $home using $homeRepository goes wrong.

This is true just for the GroupRepository's EntityManager. If i try to print spl hash of other repositories's EntityManager instances are randomly "paired":

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $groupRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $homeRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $furnitureRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $detailRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');

    die(print_r([spl_object_hash($groupRepo->getEntityManager()),
        spl_object_hash($homeRepo->getEntityManager()),
        spl_object_hash($manager), spl_object_hash($furnitureRepo->getEntityManager(), spl_object_hash($detailRepo->getEntityManager()], true));
}

// RESULT
Array
(
    [0] => 0000000016c61829000000003b475624 // A
    [1] => 0000000016c61f96000000003b475624 // B
    [2] => 0000000016c61829000000003b475624 // A
    [3] => 0000000016c61f96000000003b475624 // B
    [4] => 0000000016c61829000000003b475624 // A
)
```

Next test was to try to get Repositories directly from ObjectManager

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $homeRepo = $manager->getRepository('Domain:Home');
    $groupRepo = $manager->getRepository('Domain:Group');
    $furnitureRepo = $manager->getRepository('Domain:Furniture');
    $detailRepo = $manager->getRepository('Domain:Detail');

    die(print_r([spl_object_hash($groupRepo->getEntityManager()),
        spl_object_hash($homeRepo->getEntityManager()),
        spl_object_hash($manager), spl_object_hash($furnitureRepo->getEntityManager(), spl_object_hash($detailRepo->getEntityManager()], true));
}

// RESULT
Array
(
    [0] => 0000000025c5506b0000000042ab38bc
    [1] => 0000000025c5506b0000000042ab38bc
    [2] => 0000000025c5506b0000000042ab38bc
    [3] => 0000000025c5506b0000000042ab38bc
    [4] => 0000000025c5506b0000000042ab38bc
)
```

I've lost plenty of hours trying to understand what is going on here, anyone have a suggestion?

- PHP 7.2.7
- doctrine/orm v2.6.1 and v2.6.2
- symfony/symfony v3.4.11

**EDIT: SOLVED THE SITUATION - BUG/PROBLEM REMAINS**

So, i've found a way to have a consistent EntityManager across my repositories using **@doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory**:

```
repository.group:
    class: Infrastructure\Persistence\DoctrineORM\Repository\GroupRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory", getRepository]
    arguments:
      - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
      - 'Domain\Entity\Group'
repository.home:
    class: Infrastructure\Persistence\DoctrineORM\Repository\HomeRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory", getRepository]
    arguments:
    - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
    - 'Domain\Entity\Home'
...


public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $groupRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $homeRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $furnitureRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');
    $detailRepo = $this->container->get('groupRepo');

    print_r([
        spl_object_hash($homeRepo->getEM()),
        spl_object_hash($groupRepo->getEM()),
        spl_object_hash($furnitureRepo->getEM()),
        spl_object_hash($detailRepo->getEM())], true));
}

// RESULT
Array
(
    [0] => 0000000066defdbc00000000687b521b
    [1] => 0000000066defdbc00000000687b521b
    [2] => 0000000066defdbc00000000687b521b
    [3] => 0000000066defdbc00000000687b521b
)
```

Now the `$userRepo->save($user)` works well.

I really can't understand why using `factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]` generate inconsistent EntityManager instances across the repositories while using `factory: ["@doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory", getRepository]` have better stability. Don't really know if this is the real problem of my situation, because last week everything worked smooth and after some hardcore refactoring this stop working well

Comment: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/iyan/using-composition-over-inheritance-for-doctrine-repository-in-symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was able to reach the same workaround as you, through debugging and trial/error.

There are several possible root causes.

1) There was a bug in Symfony-Doctrine bundle: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30091 - solution would be to upgrade to the Symfony version where it was fixed

2) Tagging a service with "doctrine.event_listener" also can cause this. You end up with 2 different instances of UnitOfWork in entity manager and in repositories.
To work around this, declare event listeners with "lazy" parameter. For example:

```
  AppBundle\Service\Foo\Listener:
tags:
  - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush, method: onFlush, lazy: true }
  - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush, method: postFlush, lazy: true }
```